# Do I have to open pull request every time?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

Working with Azure DevOps, I create a branch out of Dev branch.

When I open a pull request, it includes all the commits from the Dev branch.

Do I need to open a pull request even on opening a new branch?

This way it will give me the option to open a "clean" pull request only with my newly added files,

But is it the only way to get "Clean" pull requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to open a pull request even on opening a new branch?

The answer is no.

As we know, the Pull request could:

> let your team review code and give feedback on changes before merging
>   it into the master branch. Pull requests can come from either topic
>   branches within the same repository or from a branch in a fork of the
>   original repository. Reviewers can step through the proposed changes,
>   leave comments, and vote to approve or reject the code.

With pull request, the code in the branch are protected. When we opening a new branch out of Dev branch, lets call it `feature` branch without any modification, we do not need to open a pull request, that because there is no any new change in the new `feature` branch.

[image]

> This way it will give me the option to open a "clean" pull request
>   only with my newly added files

If we create the `feature` branch **based on** `Dev` branch, make any change on the feature branch, then create pull request to merge `feature` branch to `Dev` branch, it **only include newly added files**:

[image]

But if merge `feature` branch to other branch, not the `Dev` branch, it will not only include newly added files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Small question: Lets say I open a feature A branch, commit, open pull request to Dev branch. Then, I create feature B branch out of feature A branch. Commit, open a pull request to dev. The request will include all commits done on A branch, since they are not yet merged to Dev. But I want my peers to only review the changes included in commits done on B branch. How do I achieve that?

Comment: @o_w, Thanks your reply. I got you. But I am afraid there is no such a way to achieve that, because Pull reques compares the commit ids of the two branches when merging the two branches. Since the commit merge of `feature A` is not completed, then the commit on the `featuer B` branch and the commit on the `dev` branch will include the unfinished on `featuer A` Commit. This is determined by the properties of git, we cannot change it for the time being.